# Use multiple SUM of COUNT in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to find the sum of count values from a query and I did that like below

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Total) AS SUMV   
FROM
    (SELECT   
         COUNT(Session.SessionID) AS Total   
     FROM 
         [Session]
     WHERE
         DateCreated >='2016-03-20' 
         AND DateCreated <= '2016-03-22'
     GROUP BY 
         CAST(DateCreated AS DATE)) s
```

Now I have to find the sum of count with a different condition and I tried to get the sum value as a second column of above table like below

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Total) AS SUMV, SUM(Total2) AS SUMV2  
FROM
    (SELECT   
         COUNT(Session.SessionID) AS Total   
     FROM 
         [Session]
     WHERE 
         DateCreated >='2016-03-20' 
         AND DateCreated <= '2016-03-22'
     GROUP BY  
         CAST(DateCreated AS DATE)) s, 
    (SELECT   
         COUNT(Session.SessionID) AS Total2   
     FROM 
         [Session]
     WHERE
         DateCreated >='2016-03-23' 
         AND DateCreated <= '2016-03-25'
     GROUP BY
         CAST(DateCreated AS DATE)) s2
```

But the SUM2 is not returning the correct `SUM` value. So is my query correct or any better way to use multiple instances of `SUM` of count in an SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the first query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Session] s
WHERE DateCreated >= '2016-03-20' AND  DateCreated <= '2016-03-22';
```

You can do multiple sums using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DateCreated >= '2016-03-20' AND  DateCreated <= '2016-03-22'
            THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS Total_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DateCreated >= '2016-03-23' AND  DateCreated <= '2016-03-25'
            THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS Total_2           
FROM [Session] s;
```

Comment: How can we make a new column as difference of value Total_1-Total_2 on this query?Since the Total_1,2 fields are generated on the fly i guess

Comment: @JibinMathew . . . That is not part of your original question.  You can either use a subquery and subtract the fields by name, or you can repeat the expressions with a `-` between them.